# RMagick - How to crop grid image into an array of images?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

The following imageMagick command will crop a sprite image into several images divided equally:

`convert image.png -crop 2x3-40-20@ +repage +adjoin tile-%d.jpg`

Hot do I do this with Rmagick? But instead of creating multiple files i need to return an array of images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to get it done by croping each image at a time:

```
def split_images
  #'image' is a ImageMagick Object
  width  = image.cols/number_cols
  height = image.rows/nubmer_rows
  images = []
  0.upto(number_rows-1) do |x|
    0.upto(number_cols-1) do |y|
      images << image.crop( Magick::NorthWestGravity, x*width, y*height, width, height, true)
    end
  end
end
```